Wordpress Custom Block Spacing (Padding and Margin) Responsive
I've spent a while building a custom block to give me a wrapper that I can theme for inner blocks. All good. I am able to add the required support in the block config (block.json):
"supports": {
        "html": false,
        "spacing": {
            "padding": ["top", "bottom"],
            "margin": ["top", "bottom"]
        }
    },

... and the required settings in theme.json:
"spacing": {
            "spacingScale": {
                "steps": 0
            },
            "spacingSizes": [
                {
                    "name": "xSmall",
                    "size": "2rem",
                    "slug": "x-small"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Small",
                    "size": "3rem",
                    "slug": "small"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Medium",
                    "size": "4rem",
                    "slug": "medium"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Large",
                    "size": "5rem",
                    "slug": "large"
                },

            ]
        }

However the whole thing breaks down when I start thinking about responsive styles. I would like to have padding and margin values that change at different breakpoints. I would normally add tailwind classes to give me responsive spacing.
Anyone come across a way to deal with this. I did think about adding attributes to the block to select spacing values (xs, s, md, l, xl) and then assign class(s) based on value selected. This just feels like a lot of work and there should be a way to get something responsive working.
I thought the clamp(x, y, z) css feature might work but the min and max values don't respond to breakpoints.
Appreciate any thoughts.

clamp() flui (relative) value can be computed using two targeted breakpoints, at which you want your two fixed vakues to be assigned - exactly as you do it with media queries.
Example: 15px until 600px - the fluid values - the 18px from 1280px.
It's just about maths.
Take a look at my article about clamp calculation here (in french, use FireFox or Safari translate function if you don't speak french) and my clamp generator here if you want a clean and speed solution.
